# Regex matching [0-9]-[A-Z0-9].wav

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following Perl code:

```
perl -ane 'm|/(..)/([1-9zo]+[ab])\.wav| || die "bad line $_"; print "$1_$2 $_";'
```

Instead of matching a file path like `/m/ad/11b.wav` I need to match a file path like:

```
/m/6-23E5CD3A14BC47154F29E25578FC4.wav
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What happens if you put the regex in the title into the program?  You'll need to adjust the part that matches two characters between slashes to allow just one; you need to add an appropriate quantifier after the second character class.  But that's just about all.

Comment: Looks like you're actually limited to hexadecimal characters so `[0-9A-Z]` may be too broad. Something like `m|/./[0-9]-[0-9A-F]{29}\.wav|`. You can also use `[[:xdigit]]`

Answer (score -1):

What form do you want $1 and $2 to be in? Do you want $1 to be like "/m"?
Do you want $2 to be "6-23..."?  Something else?

```
m|(..)/([[:digit:][:upper:]-]+)(?>\.wav)$| || die; print "$1_$2 $_";
```

This regex produces:

```
/m_6-23E5CD3A14BC47154F29E25578FC4
```